# How to add applicationSettings section in configuration file?

Tags: c#, configuration

I added a app config file to C# project and wanted to store config for log4Net and some basic app setting. The generated app.config file is empty.

I looked at other projects. They had an applicationSettings section. So I added a applicationSettings section; by copy pasting from some other project. Then I did not understand what some of the attributes were; like the PublicKeyToken b77a5c561934e089. I tried searching to see if the section is automatically generated; could not find how. The online resources point to complicated schemes about writing your own config class. My needs are far simple. Online resources do not document the attributes per se.

So short of copy pasting from some other project, how do you get around to adding this section?

```
  <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
    <section name="CrawlReponseHandler.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </sectionGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

The section is added automatically by going to project -> properties -> settings tab and adding the properties.